# What does "if not" mean in this case?

Tags: algorithm

I just started learning python. And here is the Algorithm that I don't quite understand.

```
Connected(A[0..n − 1, 0..n − 1])

  //Input: Adjacency matrix A[0..n − 1, 0..n − 1]) of an undirected graph G

  //Output: 1 (true) if G is connected and 0 (false) if it is not

  if n = 1 return 1 //one-vertex graph is connected by definition

  else

     if not Connected(A[0..n − 2, 0..n − 2]) return 0

     else for j ←0 to n − 2 do
              if A[n − 1, j] return 1
          return 0
```

So what does the `"if not"` statement mean?
Does it mean `if Connected != 1 then return 0`?

Comment: It's just an algorithm

Comment: you shouldn't use tag `python` if there is no python code.

Answer (score 2):

In this code it means

```
if Connected(...arguments...) != 1 then return 0
```

For `n = 2` it means

```
if Connected(A[0..0, 0..0]) != 1 then return 0
```

Because `Connected(A[0..0, 0..0]) == 1` (because `A[0..0,0..0]` is one-vertex graph) so code will run `else for ...`

---

BTW: you example is not python code.

Comment: Thanks! So is there a case that this algorithm doesn't work?
I'm thinking of a case of an undirected graph that this algorithm doesn't work?

Comment: For me it seems OK. It uses recurrence to checks lower triangular.If there is (at least one) value `1` in every row then it should be connected graph (but it doesn't have to be [complet graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph)).

Answer (score 1):

It just means that if the result of `Connected(...)` is `true`, then

```
not Connected(...)
```

will be `false`.

If the result of `Connected(...)` is `false`, then

```
not Connected(...)
```

will be `true`. In other words, it negates a boolean (`true` or `false`)

Comment: So let's say n = 2.
Then "if not Connected(A[0,0])" is false, so will it return 0? or will it go to the else statement?